# XML: How to recursively combine the text of identical elements in Xquery

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

How can I merge all the context that are in identical and repeated elements throughout a document using Xquery?

sample document:

```
<webMessage xmlns="http://www.website.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
<EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
<Header>
    <MessageDetails>
        <Class>Web-CT600</Class>
        <Qualifier/>
        <Function/>
    </MessageDetails>
    <SenderDetails>
        <IDAuthentication>
            <SenderID/>
            <Authentication>
                <Method/>
                <Role/>
                <Value/>
            </Authentication>
        </IDAuthentication>
    </SenderDetails>
</Header>
<webTalkDetails>
    <Keys>
        <Key Type="UTR">2274792909</Key>
    </Keys>
    <ChannelRouting>
        <Channel>
            <URI/>
            <Product/>
            <Version/>
        </Channel>
    </ChannelRouting>
</webTalkDetails>
<Body>
    <IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.website.gov.uk/taxation/CT/3">
        <IRheader>
            <Keys>
                <Key Type="UTR">2274792909</Key>
            </Keys>
            <PeriodEnd/>
            <DefaultCurrency/>
            <IRmark Type="generic">n1uS2MiavBsb6YwL82MK</IRmark>
            <Sender/>
        </IRheader>
        <CompanyReturn ReturnType="new">
            <CompanyInformation>
                <CompanyName/>
                <RegistrationNumber/>
                <Reference/>
                <PeriodCovered>
                    <From>2013-01-07</From>
                    <To>2014-01-07</To>
                </PeriodCovered>
            </CompanyInformation>
            <Turnover>
                <Total>45893</Total>
            </Turnover>
            <CompanyCalculation>
                <Income>
                    <TradingAndProfessional>
                        <Profits>95517</Profits>
                        <NetProfits>51276</NetProfits>
                    </TradingAndProfessional>
                </Income>
            </CompanyCalculation>
            <AttachedFiles>
                <Xsubmission>
                    <Accounts>
                        <Instance>
                            <EncodedInlineSubmission> TEXT I WANT TO JOIN</EncodedInlineSubmission>
                        </Instance>
                    </Accounts>
                    <Computations>
                        <Instance>
                            <EncodedInlineSubmission> MORE TEXT I WANT TO JOIN</EncodedInlineSubmission>
                        </Instance>
                    </Computations>
                </Xsubmission>

            </AttachedFiles>
        </CompanyTaxReturn>
    </IRenvelope>
</Body>
```

So in This XML here I want to combine all the text in all the instances of  and put them into one element single element so it will read:

```
<EncodedInlineSubmission> TEXT I WANT TO JOIN MORE TEXT I WANT TO JOIN</EncodedInlineSubmission>
```

Comment: The problem description is too general. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: added an element constructor around the returned string.

You can use `fn:string-join()` to join a sequence of strings with a joiner string. You'll need to evaluate an XPath expression that selects all the nodes you want to join, and then retrieve their string values.

Here's an example:

```
declare namespace env = "http://www.website.gov.uk/CM/envelope";

let $nodes := $doc/env:webMessage/env:Body//env:EncodedInlineSubmission
return element EncodedInlineSubmission { fn:string-join($nodes/fn:string(), " ") }
```

Notes:

- Assume `$doc` is bound to the document-node of your sample document
- you may need a different XPath expression
- your sample is not well-formed

Comment: But this will just return the concatenated text, not an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplye construct a new element using the concatenated values of all elements and the previous name of an element:

```
for $x in //*:Xsubmission
let $encoded := $x//*:EncodedInlineSubmission
return element {$encoded[1]/local-name()} {string-join($encoded)}
```

Comment: Hi I tried this out but I think I was a bit too broad with the example I gave. here is an example of the data structure with dummy data. I tried your code but I didnt get any results. Would you have any idea with the updated section above?

Comment: I did update my answer. However, next time please take your time before asking a question and provide a useful SSCCE. Your updated question has little to do with your original one.